# OpenCV's clustering function cvKMeans2() - what is a type of cluster center in array?

Tags: c++, opencv, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm using function cvKMeans2() from OpenCV library for clustering. It has optional parametr:
***centers -*** The optional output array of the cluster centers
The same parametr is also in function kmeans().

I want to know informations about clusters. But I haven't found what is a type of that cluster center in array, so I can't get it.

Thanks for any advices!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OpenCV 2.0, the equivalent kmeans function takes a CV_32FC1 matrix, but OpenCV 2.0 is quite a substantial upgrade to the old kmeans2 function, so I cannot be sure if the cluster centers datatype would still be the same for the OpenCV 1.1 version.

Comment: Yes, I'm using CV_32FC1 matrix. But as I was thinking more about it, I finally realized it's quite simple, that it's the same type as input. Cause it's a vector of random numbers from the same range as my input floats.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.1.0/html/045d9e85-de6a-7e81-dbf2-5fd014ae36de.htm) makes it look like the "centers" parameter has the same type as the first parameter, which [other documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/basic_structures.html#cvarr) says:

> The metatype CvArr is used only as a function parameter to specify that the function accepts arrays of multiple types, such as IplImage*, CvMat* or even CvSeq* sometimes. The particular array type is determined at runtime by analyzing the first 4 bytes of the header.

That, combined with [this question](http://n2.nabble.com/How-to-get-cluster-centers-using-cvKmeans2-td3911757.html), makes me think you should try passing a CV array (vector) to get the centers.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/clustering_and_search_in_multi-dimensional_spaces.html#cvKMeans2